# MacBook Late 2008 SSD Upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, upgrade, ssd

I have the late 2008 edition of the unibody MacBook. It has a built-in HDD which became unbelievably slow. The other tech-specs are:

[image: my tech-specs]

Now, since its not too bad regarding the processor and the memory is ok too, I thought about speeding it up a bit by giving it an SSD.

[#1] Do you think [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JN1TY9U) SSD will work for the MacBook? Or do you have another recommendation?

**EDIT**

[#2] I found an even quicker one for just 10$ more, might that one work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that drive will work for your Macbook. However, keep in mind that your machine uses a [SATA II interface](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i,-sata-ii-and-sata-iii). This means that the maximum throughout is 300 MB/s. Though SATA III drives, such as the one you link to, are backwards compatible, there’s no benefit to spending the extra money. You are better off [finding a SATA II SSD](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_1292116011_nr_p_n_feature_keywords_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A%21493964%2Cn%3A541966%2Cn%3A1292110011%2Cn%3A1292116011%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_four_browse-bin%3A6158692011&bbn=1292116011&ie=UTF8&qid=1426693927&rnid=6009674011). Either way, you will notice a drastic improvement in speed and performance.

Comment: Thank you, is it 300MB/s in- or output?

Comment: @LinusG You’re welcome. Both. You will not exceed 300 MB/S reading from it or writing to it.

Comment: How do you actually know what SATA I have? In the system info it just says "SATA", same on the official Apple Website.

Comment: @LinusG., the specs of that laptop are available in several places such as http://everymac.com. SATA III didn't appear in the Mac laptop line until the 2011 MacBook Pro (8,1).

Answer (score 1):

Yep it'll be compatible, your HDD is a SATA II.

But because of the SATA2 limitation (~300MB/s) you won't be able to use your SSD at full speed.

Comment: Oh really? So is it 300MB/s in- or output?

Comment: Both, it's the same thing for the controller.

Comment: How do you actually know what SATA I have? In the system info it just says "SATA", same on the official Apple Website.

Comment: SATA III is a standard released in 2009. SATA II is much older as it was released in 2004.

Comment: Also EveryMac is a good reference : http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-aluminum-13-late-2008-unibody-specs.html (3Gbps = SATA II)

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know how to interpret the 3Gbps

Answer (score 1):

I have that same model and have a 240GB SSD from OWC in it.  Have had for probably two years.  It works very well and since you just need a 3G model you can get one for like $125.00 or so.